# *ngFor executes many times in Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

Why *ngFor is executing many times?
And why in the AfterViewInit the offsetTop of the div is zero?

```html
<ul *ngFor="let chat of chats">
  <div id="chat{{chat.id}}">{{printItem(chat)}}</div>
</ul>
```

```js
export class HomePage implements AfterViewInit {

  chats:any[]=[
    {id:1},
    {id:2},
    {id:3},
  ];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('after view init');
    let chat:HTMLElement|null = document.querySelector("#chat3");
    console.log('offsetTop',chat?.offsetTop);
  }

  printItem(chat:any){
    console.log('chat',chat.id);
  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: It gets executed at every change detection cycle. It has nothing to do with `ngFor`. I advise you to never call a method from the component template or to use `OnPush` as ChangeDetectionStrategy

Comment: 1) don't use fuctions in bindings 2) Use the newer binding notation `[id]="'chat' + chat.id` 3) use a [`trackBy`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor#description) function 4) [Here](https://medium.com/ngconf/make-trackby-easy-to-use-a3dd5f1f733b) someone wrote a directive in order not to have to write the trackBy function all the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in the docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle

Ionic has two events after the view is rendered:
ionViewWillEnter
ionViewDidEnter

I only needed to add one of these methods in my ts file:

```
  ionViewDidEnter(){
    console.log('ionViewDidEnter');
    let phone6:HTMLElement|null = document.querySelector("#phone6");
    if(phone6 && phone6.offsetTop){
      let top = phone6.offsetTop;
      console.log(top);
    }
  }

  ionViewWillEnter(){
    console.log("ionViewWillEnter")
    let phone6:HTMLElement|null = document.querySelector("#phone6");
    if(phone6 && phone6.offsetTop){
      let top = phone6.offsetTop;
      console.log(top);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook is executed after Angular has fully initialized the component's view and its child views.

So, when you try to access the offsetTop of #chat3 inside ngAfterViewInit, the element has not yet been rendered on the screen, and its offsetTop value will be zero.

To get the correct offsetTop, you can use a different lifecycle hook like ngAfterViewChecked, which is called after every check of the component's view and the child views. In ngAfterViewChecked, you can be sure that the view and the DOM elements have been updated, and you should be able to get the correct offsetTop value for #chat3.

Answer (score 0):

Its template redraws.

Avoid using functions in in your template.

If you need to do some calculation with the chat object, then use a pipe instead, they will be memorized so the result is only calculated once and then on redraws you will get the previously calculated value.

To reduce redraws you can use changeDetectionStragegy.onPush then the template updates will reduce redraw checks to input and output changes as well as changes in | async pipe. Or if you explicitly tell the changeDetectorRef to markForChanges()

Edit:
based on the comment, sounds like you only need a specific operation on the last index of the ngFor you can use this

```
<ul *ngFor="let chat of chats; let last = last">
  <div id="chat{{chat.id}}">
     <ng-container *ngIf="last">Last chat: {{ chat.id }}</ng-container>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Actually, I only want to get the top position of the third element.

Comment: you can use let last=last in your ngFor, then you can use that boolean to to pull a different property